# In SFMC, Under Admin tab we have "Tracking configuration > Custom Tab "

Tags: marketing-cloud

In Email Studio under the "Admin"-tab we see "Tracking configuration > Custom Tab". Could anyone brief me on what's the purpose of this "custom tab"?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so others can see there is a correct answer to your question. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Nivas did this answer work for you? if it did you should accept it or comment if it was what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to create buttons in the tracking screen that link to job-level tracking information with custom dashboards for a specific tracking job:

> The Tracking Custom Tab allows you create a button in your tracking screen that links to a landing page of job-level tracking information. This enables you to pull in web analytics data, create custom reporting dashboards, and tailor summary information for a specific tracking job.
> (Source: [Marketing Cloud Documentation: Tracking Custom Tab](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/tracking_workspace/tracking_custom_tab/)

The link on the documentation page I referenced, that should take you to "How to Create a Custom Tab"-page is wrong however. This is the correct link: [Extending the User Interface of Your Account - How to Create a Custom Tab](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/account_settings/extending_the_user_interface_of_your_account/)